# Issues in automation framework for web page testing

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I am in process of building an automation tool for testing webpages. Already aware of selenium tool but will not be using that currently as our framework has already been built and requires minor changes to make it reliable. While testing this framework with test pages (html and javascript only) I encounter issues such as webpage takes a lot if time to load(happens like 1 out of 20 times). And when you try to find the co-ordinate and click the button or try to find the element in the webpage and click it sometimes it fails as button doesn't even exists at that point of time.

Currently using Thread.sleep or retry n number of times. Are there any better solutions to remove this flaky behavior?

Answer (score 2):

look into [WebDriverWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class. There is a respective binding for c# as well. Also, I have discussed the WebDriverWait [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843581/wait-for-elment-webdriver-pageobject-pattern/18844275#18844275).

Comment: I feel bad upvoting because your rep is `404 (rep not found)`, but `WebDriverWait` is a good solution.. :|

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. Currently trying this solution. I also feel this question can have many solutions. So i will wait for some more possible solutions before  there is an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Implicit waits
Read about it here http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Basically you set it once per session. If you can't find an element, selenium waits the amount of time you set before throwing the exception.